# batch file - searching by character count

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a batch file that will search in a dir for all .pdf files that have a name of 10 characters as we have many .pdf's with different characters in name so I need to sort them out and move (cut and paste) them to a 2nd directory that is prepared. Can you please help me with this batch file?

example

setdir test contain .pdfs

```
--+6570296402-1-982464371-120.pdf
+6581239585-1-982470028-120.pdf
5710101306.pdf
0-PZ-6562825.pdf
0-PZ-545515247-1-982466351-120.pdf
5455152471.pdf
```

result:

target dir - test2 - where need to be moved .pdf with 10 characters

```
5710101306.pdf
5455152471.pdf
etc
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Hire someone, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running from the current directory you could probably do this using `Where` and `Move`:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where/F .:??????????.pdf'
) Do Move /Y %%A "Test2">Nul
```

Comment: thank you so much Compo, it works very well. Much appreciated your fast help.

Answer (score 0):

```
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf') do call :select10 "%%a") >filename.txt

... more processing if required
goto :eof

:select10
set "name=%~n1"
set "name=%name:~9%"
if not defined name goto :eof
set "name=%name:~1%"
if not defined name echo %~1
goto :eof
```

This should solve the problem.

perform a `dir` list of `*.pdf`, selecting filenames only. Pass the filename found to subroutine `:select10`, in quotes in case of spaces in filename.

The subroutine set `name` first to the name part of the filename received, then removes the first 9 characters. If the result is an empty variable, skip to end-of-file. If not, select all but the first character. If the result is not an empty string, the name must be 11 or more characters - if it's empty, then `echo` the name passed in the first instance.

The parentheses around the `for` command will cause the `echo`ed data to be accumulated into the file nominated.

If you want to move the file to the destination, not simply list the selections, remove the `(` before the `for`, and the `) >filename.txt` after and replace the `echo` with `move "%1" destination\`

You could also do the same without using a subroutine as:
    for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf') do (
     set "name=%%~na"
     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
     set "name=!name:~9!"
     if defined name (
      set "name=!name:~1!"
      if not defined name move "%%a" destination\
     )
     endlocal
    )

Using `delayed expansion` to process the substringing operations.